# Doctrine ORM Fail (ClassMetadataFactory.php)

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex

recently I made an update of my project with silex 2.0 and mark me the following error mapping Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in/var/www/vhosts/server.com.mx/cmanager.server.com.mx/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 80.

This makes certain tables not all inclusive had to change database administrator and works perfect.

Have a comment or suggestion.

Thank You

Comment: On that line (in their master branch) there's use of php's short array syntax, so make sure you have at least php5.4 on the server.

Comment: Thanks Maerlyn, Thanks , had a slight suspicion that was it but preferred to corroborate with experts. Thanks for your time and comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you accidentally upgraded doctrine when upgrading to silex 2.0. If you simply ran `composer update` instead of `composer update silex/silex`, you will update all your composer dependencies, including doctrine.

As of doctrine 2.5, it no longer supports php 5.3. You can upgrade your server to PHP 5.4 or later to fix this.

Alternatively, just downgrade doctrine to version 2.4. Put this into your `composer.json`:

```
"doctrine/orm": "2.4.*
```

**Edit**: It looks like doctrine 2.5 isn't fully released yet. Do you have your `minimum-stability` flag set to allow unstable versions? If so, I would also recommend fixing that. You should not be using dev builds in a production project.

**Edit 2**: It's released now.

Comment: Thanks JustinI will follow your advice.