# Doctrine FatalErrorException in ClassMetadataFactory

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have copied a Symfony2 project from a computer to another one, but I got this error

```
FatalErrorException in D:\wamp\www\projet\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\
ClassMetadataFactory.php line 80:
Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
```

Comment: How did you copy the project?

Comment: I deleted foldesr cache and logs in app/ and then I did a copy paste all the folder that contains the project

Comment: php version problem. Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105842/doctrine-orm-fail-classmetadatafactory-php

Comment: differnt php versions?
Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105842/doctrine-orm-fail-classmetadatafactory-php

Answer (score 0):

Check your php versions on both machines or try to run

> composer update

on the new one. My guess is that you have an older version of php on the new machine